# ASP.NET Automatic logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a group project with 4 other people. We are designing a job kiosk in ASP.NET in MVC4 with embedded c#.

I am working on having the system log the user out if they are idle for 10 minutes. I need some help on how to start coding a way for the system to log the user out.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET forms authentication then it will take care of this for you by the settings in the web.config.

Comment: Keep track of the users activity and if they make a request beyond your timestamp, they need to login again. The recycler in IIS takes care of the rest if it is enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't use "Windows Authentication", this at least depends on the session timeout you can control via web.config:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="10" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

As most techniques somehow rely on sessions, this will work in most scenarios.

Comment: If he is not using Forms Authentication or Windows Authentication, he is doing it wrong. He'll be vulnerable to session fixation attacks.

http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2009/06/24/session-attacks-and-aspnet-part-2

Comment: @JeowLiHuan, One could implement or even improve the functionality of Forms Authentication without actually using it. However, the point is, I didn't make any suggestion on what technique to use because that was not part of the question. I just said that abandoning the session will log out the user as long as the authentication somehow relies on sessions, and most solutions do. Except Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 6):

the answer you are looking for is the one AliK suggested.  You want to set an automatic timeout in the web.config so that it will automatically logout the user and redirect them to the login page after a certain amount of idle time.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="true">
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

If I remember right, the timeout value is in minutes, not seconds or milliseconds.  Also the sliding Expiration means that the timeout will reset each time you perform an action on the website.  So if you have a timeout of 5 minutes and you sit idle for 4 before clicking a button on the site then after the button click you get a new 5 minute timeout.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't automatically redirect the user. I like Vinny's suggestion of adding the Refresh header in the Applicaiton_BeginRequest but does that mean I have to add the global.asax just for this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do it if you are using FormsAuthentication:

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult CheckLogin()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["CookieName"] == null) return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["CookieName"].Value;
    var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie);
    var secondsRemaining = Math.Round((ticket.Expiration - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds, 0);
    return Json(secondsRemaining, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Jquery on each page or on layout page:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
    });
    function doStuff() {
        $.ajax("/CheckLogin").done(function (data) {
            if (data <= 60) {
                startLogout(data);
            } else {
                setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    function startLogout(seconds) {
        var countdown = setInterval(function () {
            //Show something here
            if (count == 0) {
                clearInterval(countdown);
                //Do something here
            }
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have them automatically logged out, start with Linus Caldwell's suggestion of setting the web.config session timeout. His example shows 30 minutes, so you would just change it to 10. The user won't know that they're logged out, though, until they actually try to request some server resource. To have that happen automatically, you can go a couple of ways. Both of these ways involve automatically refreshing the page after the timeout period has expired. One way is to use a javascript timer. The other is to add a refresh header to each page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var seconds = 60 * 11;// set timer for 11 minutes (1 minutes after session expires)
countdown();
function countdown(){
   seconds--;
   if (seconds <= 0){
          window.location.reload(); // force a refresh.
   }else{
          setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
   }
}
</script>
```

The other way would be in your global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Refresh", Convert.ToString(Session.Timeout * 11));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by Idle you mean absence of mouse and keyboard events from user, and i understand your requirement correctly, you should check the  [jquery-idleTimeout](https://github.com/philpalmieri/jquery-idleTimeout) plugin.

Another good one is [jQuery idleTimer Plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/)

hope this helps.