# ASP.NET Forms Authentication Timeout and Session Timeout

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using forms authentication in asp.net. I have set timeout to 1   minute. As soon I login, if authenticated  I will be redirected to Home Page (HomePage.aspx). This is working fine. If I stay away from the website and comes back after 1 minute, and try to access any other page, I will redirected to Login page as expected. My question is, if I come back and do some post back or refresh, then only I am redirected to login page otherwise I will be staying on same page. What should I do in order to login page to appear on screen if I come back after 1 minute.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms  loginUrl="~/LoginPage.aspx"  timeout="1"/>
</authentication>

<sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answers. Below post also helped.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991652/asp-net-automatic-logout

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Session_End` in `Global.asax` then try to put some code to redirect to your login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [asp-net-push-redirect-on-session-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484964/asp-net-push-redirect-on-session-timeout). This SO post shows the way to redirect using `<meta>` in page header section. I have not tested it but I doubt setting the `<meta>`, it may always redirect after session timeout even for non-logged in pages particularly in case it is implemented in `MasterPages`.

If you do not want to use headers or you want custom JavaScript based solution you can do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // get session timeout value
    var sessionTimeout = '<%= Session.Timeout %>';
    // convert from minutes to ms
    var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeout) * 60 * 1000;
    setTimeout('SessionWarning()', sTimeout);

    function SessionWarning() {
        // use a session variables (User_ID) that confirms we have a logged in user
        var userid = '<%= Session("User_ID") %>';

        // ignore for pages that can be viewed without login. In that case User_ID will not be set
        // also on session end User_ID needs to be set to zero/null/blank
        if (userid == '') {

        } else {
            if (parseInt(userid) > 0) {
                // if the user is logged in redirect to login page on session timeout
                window.location.href= '/LoginPage.aspx';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can place this script on the page for which you want auto redirect or on a `MasterPage` for using on all pages.